# Dividing two signed 32 bit in assembly (x86-64)

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am given two numbers and required to divide them.

I figured that the first step would be to move the dividend to `EAX`, but I also believe that `EDX` should be `0xffffffff` if the sign of the dividend is negative and `0` if it's positive.

The problem is that I don't know how to this. Perhaps I should use some shifting instruction and then assign the value by hand depending on the result, but I am not really sure how to get the MSB of the dividend and how check whether it's `0` or `1`. What is a good way to do this?

Please use basic instructions only (like jump, shift, mov, cmp and arithmetic operations). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, sign-extending EAX into EDX:EAX is the first step before `idiv` (with a 32-bit divisor).  x86 has an instruction for this, called `cdq`.  You can emulate it using `mov edx, eax` / `sar edx, 31` to broadcast the sign bit of EAX to all bits of EDX.

Comment: Maybe I was hasty closing this as a duplicate since you're asking for how to do it "manually" with basic instructions, not just the standard recipe.  Oh, but my answer there does mention the mov/sar way to emulate CDQ so that's ok.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.